# How can I listen to INTERNAL changes in a tableview?

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8, observablelist

I have a TableView whose items contain checkboxes. As soon as 2 checkboxes are selected, I need to "unhide" a button.

I have no idea how to check that. Do you have an approach?

- The items don't know each other.
- The TableView-Controller holds the TableView and the TableColumns.

As far as I know you cannot use bindings here, since you cannot bind yourself to multiple properties. I'm glad for every kind of help. :)

**EDIT:** To clarify myself: tableView.getItems().addListener() won't work since this can only listen to modifications to the list and not to the outer elements. It can notice if "add()" or "remove" was called, but that's basically it as far as I know.

PS: Busy waiting in a seperate thread is no solution of course.

Comment: Your checkboxes are bound to some `BooleanProperty` of your items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a `TableView<Item>` for some `Item` class with a `BooleanProperty`:

```
public class Item {

    private final BooleanProperty checked = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    public BooleanProperty checkedProperty() {
        return checked ;
    }

    public final boolean isChecked() {
        return checkedProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        checkedProperty().set(checked);
    }

    // other properties, etc...
}
```

and your checkboxes are bound to this property, then you can create your items list using an extractor:

```
ObservableList<Item> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(item -> 
    new Observable[] { item.checkedProperty() });
table.setItems(items);
```

This ensures that the list fires update notifications when the `checkedProperty` changes on any of its elements.

So now you can just do normal binding stuff like:

```
IntegerBinding numberChecked = Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> 
    (int) items.stream().filter(Item::isChecked).count(),
    items);

button.visibleProperty().bind(numberChecked.greaterThanOrEqualTo(2));
```

If you want to be super-efficient:

```
int requiredNumberChecked = 2 ;
button.visibleProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() ->
    items.stream()
        .filter(Item::isSelected)
        .skip(requiredNumberChecked-1)
        .findAny().isPresent(), 
    items));
```

(the binding will return true as soon as it finds two checked items, instead of scanning the entire list).

Comment: This looks like a deluxe version, thank you. I don't understand the "new Observable[]" part though. In my understanding, this creates an Observable object which shouldn't fit into "ObservableList<Item". I soon finish work, but I will come back to this tomorrow. Thanks! :)

Comment: See [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-), and maybe just [search this site](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+observablelist+extractor) for "ObservableList" and "extractor".